# Hadoop mapReduce - difference between RecordReader´s parsing logic and Writeable.readFields()

Tags: java, serialization, hadoop

I´m currently working on a mapReduce job processing xml data and I think there´s something about the data flow in hadoop that I´m not getting correctly.

I´m running on Amazon´s ElasticMapReduce service.

Input data: large files (significantly above 64MB, so they should be splitable), consisting of a lot of small xml files that are concatenated by a previous s3distcp operation that concatenates all files into one.

I am using a slightly modified version of Mahout´s XmlInputFormat to extract the individual xml snippets from the input.

As a next step I´d like to parse those xml snippets into business objects which should then be passed to the mapper.

Now here is where I think I´m missing something: In order for that to work, my business objects need to implement the Writable interface, defining how to read/write an instance from/to an DataInput or DataOutput.
However, I don´t see where this comes into play - the logic needed to read an instance of my object is already in the InputFormat´s record reader, so why does the object have to be capable of reading/writing itself??

I did quite some research already and I know (or rather assume) WritableSerialization is used when transferring data between nodes in the cluster, but I´d like to understand the reasons behind that architecture.

The InputSplits are defined upon job submission - so if the name node sees that data needs to be moved to a specific node for a map task to work, would it not be sufficient to simply send the raw data as a byte stream? Why do we need to decode that into Writables if the RecordReader of our input format does the same thing anyway?

I really hope someone can show me the error in my thoughts above, many thanks in advance!